# How to render exact colors?

Tags: rendering, animation, color

I can't find the way to have in the video (simple animation with Flat colors) exact HEX colors that I set in materials.

I set :

- Blender > Render Properties > Color management > View Transform : Standard.
- Light : Sun

My file is here, if you have any idea :

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#settings These are the options

Comment: Your web site wasn't serving blend files properly, so I used the rmb and select "Save link as" to copy it to my computer and then to blend-exchange.  In the future, you might prefer using blend-exchange (([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) as that's the most approachable place to store files.

Comment: Use *Emission* nodes for the *Principled BSDF*s. For some reason, the result still has tiny color variations (dither). You can see it in Gimp when you adjust the color curves or check the histogram. The hex codes of the picked colors reveals it, too: F95278 <-> F85177 or F9D81A <-> F9D81B. This is not visible to the naked eye.

Comment: Have you tried using an emission shader already? Otherwise please elaborate on your goal.